# Protect api routes with middleware in nextJS?

Tags: authentication, next.js, middleware, auth0

I'm new to next.js and I wanted to know if I could protect a whole API route via middleware. So for example if i wanted to protect `/api/users` Could I create `/api/users/_middleware.ts` and handle authentication in the middleware and not have to worry about authentication in the actual api endpoints? If so, how would I go about doing that? The library i'm using right now is `@auth0\nextjs-auth0` so I guess it would look something like this? (Also please forgive me if I code this wrong, I am doing this in the stackoverflow editor)

```js
export default authMiddleware(req,res)=>{
const {user,error,isLoading} = whateverTheNameOfTheAuth0HookIs()
if(user)
{
// Allow the request to the api route
}
else
{
// Deny the request with HTTP 401
}
}
```

Do I have the general idea correct?

Answer (score 1):

next-auth v4 introduced middleware for this purpose. The basic use case is pretty simple.
You can add a middleware.js file with the following:

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"
export const config = { matcher: ["/dashboard"] }
```

Other use cases can be found in the [documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#middleware)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to define middlewares in next.js >= v12.2.0 is a single file located at the same level as your `pages` directory, i.e `<root>/middleware`.

When the middleware feature was in Beta, it was allowed to place a middleware-file in each folder, but not anymore.

From the documentation:

> ## Nested Middleware Why This Error Occurred
>
> ### You are defining a Middleware file in a location different from <root>/middleware, which is not allowed.
>
> While in beta, a Middleware file under specific pages would only be
> executed when pages below its declaration were matched, allowing
> nesting Middleware files. Based on customer feedback, we have replaced
> this API with a single root Middleware.
>
> ### Possible Ways to Fix It Declare your Middleware in the root folder and
>
> use NextRequest parsed URL to define which path the Middleware should
> be executed for.
>
> For example, a Middleware at pages/about/_middleware.ts can move the
> logic to /middleware.ts in the root of your repository. Then, a
> conditional statement can be used to only run the Middleware when it
> matches the about/* path:
>
> ```
> // <root>/middleware.ts 
> import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
>
> export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {   if
> (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/about')) {
>     // This logic is only applied to /about   }
>
>   if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard')) {
>     // This logic is only applied to /dashboard   } }
> ```
>
> If you have more than one Middleware, you should combine them into a
> single file and model their execution depending on the incoming
> request.// /middleware.ts import type { NextRequest } from

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/nested-middleware

Answer (score -2):

You can use middleware for that, something similar to [this example](https://github.com/vercel/examples/blob/main/edge-functions/basic-auth-password/pages/_middleware.ts) from the documentation.

For a sub-directory inside `pages`, you can create a `_middleware.ts` file. It will run for all pages in this directory. It looks something like this:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const basicAuth = req.headers.get('authorization')

  if (basicAuth) {
    // do whatever checks you need here
    const hasAccess = ...

    if (hasAccess) {
      // will render the specified page
      return NextResponse.next()
    }
  }

  // will not allow access
  return new Response('No access', {
    status: 401,
    headers: {
      'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Secure Area"',
    },
  })
}
```

You can find more info in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware).

Comment: I see how it could work with basic auth but do you think it would also work with a third party authentication library like the one i'm using?